# SSMS 2016 Maintenance Plan Designer Perms

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms, sql-server-2016

We have some older maintenance plans that were built with SSMS 2014 on a Sql Server 2014 instance.  The connection defined for the plan uses a Sql Server account with sysadmin perms.  When you edit with SSMS 2014, all works just fine.  On my local box, I have SSMS 2016, also have sysadmin perms.  When I edit the plan, the "Notify Operator Task" has a blue indicator that something is wrong

[image: Error]

When I try to edit the task, I get the following error:
[image]

The sql error log shows the following errors:

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
Login failed for user 'SqlAccount'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: xx.x.x.x]
```

The SqlAccount is the one defined in my "manage connections" from the maintenance plan.  Is there some new permission that SSMS 2016 needs?  Are plans created in SSMS 2014 not fully compatible with the SSMS 2016 editor?

Comment: Are you using version 13.0.15600.2?

Comment: I am not.  I will update when I get the chance and retest my issue.

Comment: I updated SSMS to that version.  Error still occurs.

Comment: I think the blue indicator is just the way the icon looks in the new SSMS version; it doesn't necessarily mean anything is wrong as the icons changed with SSMS switching from VS 2010 to VS 2015 shell. In trying to reproduce your steps, I created a plan on a 2014 server with the 2014 SSMS with the Notify Operator Task. I then saved this plan and opened it on the 2016 SSMS and had no issues. What version SQL Server 2014 are you using? I'm using 12.0.5000. Other than that, the only thing I can think of is wrong password stored for SqlAccount user in connection.

Comment: Antoine, Thanks for testing.  My SSMS 2014 version is 12.0.4439.1.  However, I am unsure now, what version of SSMS was used to create the plan.  Maybe it was older?  I know there are known issues with old SSMS version plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your maintenance plan's "Manage Connections" define a new connection with integrated Windows authentication. Use that connection with your Notify Operator Task (set it here right-clik->Properties->Connection) and it should work.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Do you have an explanation?